# SQL Join / union question [beginer]

Tags: join

I have two tables, shown below, with the following columns:

[table #Completed]
Client_ID, ClientName, FirstDeliveryStatus, FirstDeliveryDate

[table #Planned]
Client_ID, ClientName, NextDeliveryStatus, NextDeliveryDate

[image]

As you can see clients have some completed & planned deliveries. I'm trying to merge both tables to show for each patient :

Client_ID, ClientName, FirstDeliveryStatus, FirstDeliveryDate, NextDeliveryStatus, NextDeliveryDate

I have tried to select data from table Completed and outer/inner join table Planned but it does not realy work for me. Main issue is row 6[Ashton] who have never had any completed deliveries & once I join details about his planned delivery - i'm getting nulls on Client_ID & ClientName

I would expect to see output as per below visualization

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you showed us the *exact* query used to produce that table with the combined data of the other two.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - The combined table is stated to be a visualization - presumably built manually. If OP had a query that returned that combined data, then he probably wouldn't be asking how to create that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first decide: Which table do I want to return all records for?

The answer for you sounds like "Client". So start with your client table:

```
SELECT ClientID, ClientName
FROM Client
```

Then ask: Which tables do I want to add?

The answer for you sounds like "Completed" and "Planned". So join them to Client:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.ClientName
FROM Client AS c
JOIN Completed AS comp ON c.ClientID = comp.ClientID
JOIN Planned AS p ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID
```

Now ask: Do I want to return all fields from my Client table, or only those that have matching records in both tables?

The answer for you appears to be: "All records from client and any matching from other tables". So for this, outer join to the tables from your base and return the columns you want:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.ClientName, comp.FirstDeliveryStatus, comp.FirstDeliveryDate, p.NextDeliveryStatus, p.NextDeliveryDate
FROM Client AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Completed AS comp ON c.ClientID = comp.ClientID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Planned AS p ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID
```

Now if you only wish to have records which have a record in Completed or Planned tables, add in a filter:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.ClientName, comp.FirstDeliveryStatus, comp.FirstDeliveryDate, p.NextDeliveryStatus, p.NextDeliveryDate
FROM Client AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Completed AS comp ON c.ClientID = comp.ClientID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Planned AS p ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID
WHERE p.ClientID IS NOT NULL OR comp.ClientID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What about a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Sure, whatever floats your boat :-)

Comment: A `FULL OUTER JOIN` between `#Completed` and `#Planned` would work very well, if there is no `Client` table. Note: there really *needs* to be a `Client` table, if for no other reason than to ensure `ClientID` remains a unique identifier. On the other hand, if there's a chance that there's a `ClientID` in either of the other two tables that's not in the `Client` table, you'd be back to getting NULL `ClientID` and `ClientName`.

Comment: NOTE: if using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between `#Completed` and `#Planned`, without a `Client` table, the first two items in the `SELECT` list would be `COALESCE(comp.ClientID, p.ClientID) as ClientID, COALESCE(comp.ClientName, p.ClientName) as ClientName` (or, if you prefer, use `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE`; results would be the same).

Comment: Agree - I have assumed there is a client table (i.e. the database is designed to 3NF). If there is not... well... it will be very difficult to get queries that produce the right results. The FULL OUTER as you suggest would only work for the currently visible example data. (for example what if there are different ID-Name matches in both tables).

Comment: Thank you guys for you input - thanks to your comments i have successfully created query  that do the job.